# Cannot get username of user by id Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I tried getting the username with this:

```
client.users.cache.get(obj[message.author.id]["members"][i]).username
```

Where obj is a parsed JSON file and members is a string array. The console returns:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined
```

I am 100% sure the id is correct, I even tried setting a var to the id of which I want to get the username and it worked, but when used with the `obj[message.author.id]["members"][i]` it just doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure that `obj[message.author.id]["members"][i]` is not `undefined`?

Comment: `username` is a User Object property. Make sure you aren't accessing a member.

Comment: Log obj[message.author.id]["members"] and see what you get